# Apache2 add multiple IP addresses to Location "require ip"?

Tags: httpd, apache2

The following does not work:

apache2.conf:

```
<Location>
    Require ip 192.168., 175.
</Location>
```

How can I add multiple IP ranges?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax from [mod_authz_core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html) allows adding multiple ranges on the same line, but they are separated by spaces instead of commas.

> ```
> Require [not] entity-name [entity-name]
> ```

The [Access Control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) explains the accepted formats for IP addresses.

> ```
> Require host address
> Require ip ip.address
> ```
>
> In the first form, *address* is a fully qualified domain name (or a
> partial domain name); you may provide multiple addresses or domain
> names, if desired.
>
> In the second form, *ip.address* is an IP address, a partial IP address, a network/netmask pair, or a network/nnn CIDR specification. Either IPv4 or IPv6 addresses may be used.

So your single line options are:

- `Require ip 192.168. 175.` (partial IP addresses)
- `Require ip 192.168.0.0/16 175.0.0.0/8` (CIDR notations)
- `Require ip 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 175.0.0.0/255.0.0.0` (network/netmask pairs)

If you wish to add the conditions on separate lines, you need to specify how they should be treated: access should be granted if **any** of the IP subnets matches. It's even ok to mix the formats.

```
<RequireAny>
    Require ip 192.168.
    Require ip 175.0.0.0/8
</RequireAny>
```

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to tell 100% what you're after but you need to use CIDR spec IP addressing. So IPADDRESS/MASK, e.g.

Require ip 192.168.1.0/24

That'd permit 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254

Comment: Well I just want to add any Ip ranges from `192.168.*` and any `175.*`. Using a single statement like `Require ip 192.168.` works, but how can I allow multiple ip addresses?

Comment: @membersound - that is what this answer tells you how to do.  192.168.0.0/16 would get all 192.168.*.* addresses, and 175.0.0.0/8 would get 175.*.*.* (weird combination to require... that covers LOTS of public address space, but that is what you asked for)

Comment: Well yes, but *how* exactly can I add now multiple IP ranges to the `<Location>` tag? Do I have to comma separate the IP ranges? Or repeat the statements?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `Require` lines.

```
<Location /target>
  Require ip 192.168.0.0/16
  Require ip 175.0.0.0/8
</Location>
```

If any of them match, access will be granted.